# NetSuite web serices in C#, setting approvalstatus

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

We've got a project going where we would like to be able to set a Purchase Order to being approved through web services.  We cannot find how to do this and every PO created through our web service operations go in pending approval.

supervisorApproval doesn't seem to do it

and setting orderStatus does not appear to function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines should do it:

```
po.supervisorApproval = true;
po.supervisorApprovalSpecified = true;
```

or

```
po.orderStatus = PurchaseOrderOrderStatus._pendingBilling; (or whatever status you want it to go to)
po.orderStatusSpecified = true;
```

Make sure you have the second line listed. If both are there check the integration log and see if your supervisor approval is being sent to NetSuite. Null values will not appear on the request.